# Is there any possibility for writing a test cases for property file.?

Tags: java, web-services

I have two property file.

```
email.account.active=Your Account is Activate properly.
user.intilaize.apps:Your apps initialize.
```

Here for above property file have i have some piece of web service code. for this by the help of key i can call the value at runtime.

```
According to my previous scenario all property file calling was proper.
And now value become update for all property file.
```

So here i want  to know,Is there any possibility for writing a test cases for property file.?

Comment: testing should be done for your production code, not for the property file. Test your code that it is functional for whatever the property file gives you. This means valid and invalid property files. But you cannot test a property file

Comment: @EmersonCod I disagree. He could write some kind of "Config checker" tool that simply tries to read every key that the app expects and outputs a report for which keys it went ok and what keys are missing or producing problems ... But I wouldn't consider this a "Test-Case" but a separate tool.

Comment: @Fildor, yes I agree that there should be a validation system to check for the correctness of e.g. a property file. Test-case wise I still think that the test for the production code should be existing, and not for the config file it self. That said, when talking e.g. unit test, I rather expect to not having a test case for configuration files there